# How to correctly delete background of gif image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I'm trying to delete the background of a gif image. After deleting the background of the image animation, it's no longer playing correctly.

How do I correct for the incorrect changes occurring here:

**Original:**

[image: Original]

**The problem, after background removal:**

[image: incorrect background removal]

Comment: How did you try to remove the background?

Comment: I select background color with color range and then right click on the selected section and choose reverse color . at the final I click mask. I repeat this work for all layer .After delete background animation play currently in photoshop but when display in browser play such as above image

Answer (score 2):

By default GIF images save the first frame. All subsequent frames are defined as changes compared to the frame before them. The renderer draws these changes over the previous frame. Drawing a transparent pixel over something else has little effect. This is most likely the cause of your problem.

Now to solve it. You have to adjust the [frame disposal method](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-frame-animations.html#main-pars_heading_15) in photoshop. According to the linked page it is done as follows:

1. Select the frames to alter the disposal method.
2. Right click the "frame thumbnail" to display the context menu.
3. Select "Dispose".

The documentation states that "automatic" should yield the correct result. This however seems to not be the case here. Therefore you have to force each frame to redraw by discarding the previous. This probably results in a tad bigger image.

Comment: @programmer138200: Welcome to Graphic Design! Please read the short introductory [tour] some time. If an answer helped you, consider *accepting* it; adding a "thanks" comment is obsolete. See [Help! Someone answers my question, what to do next?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the [Help].